# PayPal SOAP message format

Tags: soap, paypal, request, message

I want to get the details about a payment but I don't know how the soap message should look like. I'll show you the main steps I have to follow in order to create the message, from the [PaymentDetails API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/):

> Use the PaymentDetails API operation to obtain information about a
>   payment. You can identify the payment by the pay key associated with
>   the payment.
>
> **PaymentDetailsRequest Message**
>
> The PaymentDetailsRequest message contains the identifier used to
>   retrieve information about the payment.
>
> **PaymentDetailsRequest Fields**
>
> 1. payKey (xs:string) - The pay key that identifies the payment for which you want to retrieve details
> 2. requestEnvelope (common:RequestEnvelope) -  Information common to each API operation, such as the language in which an error message is
>      returned.
>
> **RequestEnvelope Fields**
>
> 1. errorLanguage (xs:string) - RFC 3066 language in which error messages are returned; by default it is en_US, which is the only
>      language currently supported.

This is one of their error messages:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns3:FaultMessage 
    xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
    <responseEnvelope>
        <timestamp>2013-12-07T02:08:42.623-08:00</timestamp>
        <ack>Failure</ack>
        <correlationId>3dsfdsfdsfdsf</correlationId>
        <build>1233333</build>
    </responseEnvelope>
    <error>
        <errorId>550001</errorId>
        <domain>PLATFORM</domain>
        <subdomain>Application</subdomain>
        <severity>Error</severity>
        <category>Application</category>
        <message>User is not allowed to perform this action</message>
    </error>
</ns3:FaultMessage>
```

So I thought to create a similar message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns3:PaymentDetailsRequestMessage 
    xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
    <payKey>AP-123456C</payKey>
    <requestEnvelope>
        <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
    </requestEnvelope>
</ns3:PaymentDetailsRequestMessage>
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Could you please help me create the SOAP message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample of a successful PaymentDetails request I just made and the response I got back from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PaymentDetailsRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  </requestEnvelope>
  <payKey xmlns="">AP-84R2524843917081W</payKey>
  <transactionId xmlns="">1BM714721N413291D</transactionId>
</PaymentDetailsRequest>



<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:PaymentDetailsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <responseEnvelope>
    <timestamp>2013-12-08T03:05:51.460-08:00</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <correlationId>c0ea3754bbf7e</correlationId>
    <build>7935900</build>
  </responseEnvelope>
  <cancelUrl>http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Cancel.php</cancelUrl>
  <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
  <paymentInfoList>
    <paymentInfo>
      <transactionId>65A0503076751280F</transactionId>
      <transactionStatus>COMPLETED</transactionStatus>
      <receiver>
        <amount>10.00</amount>
        <email>sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com</email>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <paymentType>SERVICE</paymentType>
        <accountId>E7BTGVXBFSUAU</accountId>
      </receiver>
      <refundedAmount>0.00</refundedAmount>
      <pendingRefund>false</pendingRefund>
      <senderTransactionId>1BM714721N413291D</senderTransactionId>
      <senderTransactionStatus>COMPLETED</senderTransactionStatus>
    </paymentInfo>
    <paymentInfo>
      <receiver>
        <amount>5.00</amount>
        <email>usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com</email>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <invoiceId>123-ABCDEF</invoiceId>
        <paymentType>SERVICE</paymentType>
        <accountId>C9TAVNJFATXCS</accountId>
      </receiver>
      <refundedAmount>0.00</refundedAmount>
      <pendingRefund>false</pendingRefund>
    </paymentInfo>
  </paymentInfoList>
  <returnUrl>http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Return.php</returnUrl>
  <senderEmail>bogus@domain.com</senderEmail>
  <status>INCOMPLETE</status>
  <payKey>AP-84R2524843917081W</payKey>
  <actionType>PAY</actionType>
  <feesPayer>EACHRECEIVER</feesPayer>
  <reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError>false</reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError>
  <sender>
    <email>bogus@domain.com</email>
    <accountId>YW66KXBKJRRES</accountId>
    <useCredentials>false</useCredentials>
  </sender>
</ns2:PaymentDetailsResponse>
```